# How to find motherboard specs

Tags: ssd, sata

I would like to upgrade my Sony Vaio VPC-EJ3S1R by replacing the DVD drive with an SSD. Only problem is, I can't find any information on its SATA interface speed so I cannot choose an SSD model. Where can I find these specifications?

---

**Solution:** Found this solution http://www.ghacks.net/2012/12/28/find-out-if-your-pc-supports-sata-mode-3-0-6gbs/ It works perfectly for me: http://www.sisoftware.net/?d=&f=home&l=en&a=

Comment: Well you should find the motherboard model written on it somewhere. Will Google not do at this point?

Comment: It does not matter what you choose it will work at the fastest speed your motherboard can support.  You don't want the junk that actually is at the speed your motherboard supports trust me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the program CPU-Z, its portable and free. When you open it, go to the mainboard tab. There you should see the manufacture and the model.
http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html - link to the program.